# Calculating effective address translation time

Tags: caching, memory-management, tlb

Does anyone know the formula for calculating the effective address-translation time?

For example, how to solve following problem:

> Given an information as below:
>
> - The TLB can hold 1024 entries and can be accessed in 1 clock cycle (1 nsec).
> - A page table entry can be found in 100 clock cycles or 100 nsec.
> - The average page replacement time is 6 msec.
>
> If page references are handled by the TLB 99% of the time, and only 0.01% lead to a page fault, what is the effective address-translation time?

So is it 1 nsec + (0.01% x 100 nsec) ?

Comment: I smell a homework question.  Nonetheless, your answer is not right.  What about page faults?

Comment: I cannot believe they teach such useless stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the data in the question, in case of address translation (virtual-to-physical), following would happen:

- with 0.99 probability, needed physical address would be in TLB (access time 1 ns)
- with 0.01 probability, needed physical address would not be in TLB, and for such cases

  - with 0.0001 probability, page fault would happen (access time 6000000 ns)
  - with 0.01-0.0001 = 0.0099 probability, page fault would not happen (access time 100 ns)

The average access time would than be 0.99 * 1 ns + 0.0001 * 6000000 ns + 0.0099 * 100 ns = ***601.98 ns***.

Comment: Please stop with those [tlb] tag edits, you are completely ruining my front page with all of those re-activated old questions.  Mass retagging needs to be okayed at meta first.

Comment: Ok, no problem! @HansPassant

Answer (score -1):

All correct but u just need to add one time memory access too. bcz ur formula says what time it will take if hit and same if miss but after that

Comment: Please don't write using "u" or "ur" or "bcz" on StackOverflow.   From the SO how to answer guide: Write to the best of your ability
We don't expect every answer to be perfect, but answers with correct spelling, punctuation, and grammar are easier to read. They also tend to get upvoted more frequently. Remember, you can always go back at any time and edit your answer to improve it.